# interaction.options.getUser is not a function

Tags: nodejs, discord.js

Hola soy nuevo en esto de escrbir aqui. Nesecito ayuda, Basicamente estoy haciendo un sistema de economia para mi bot de discord v14 y me sale este error, ya probe muchas cosas y nada.

cambie getUser por targetMembers y sigue igual.
si pongo interaction.author.id  me sale un error tambien.
Ayuda porfavor si no soluciono esto no puedo seguir con el sistema de economia.

````
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("balance")
  .setDescription("Observa cual es tu balance o de otro user.")
  .addUserOption((option) =>
    option
     .setName("target")
     .setDescription("el usuario del que le gustaría ver el saldo.")
  ),
  
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const selectedUser = interaction.options.getUser('target') || interaction.user;
    const storedBalance = await client.getBalance(selectedUser.id, interaction.guild.id);

    if (!storedBalance) return await interaction.reply({
      content: `${selectedUser.tag}, No tiene cuenta con dinero.`,
      ephemeral: true
    });
    else {
      const embedecon = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`Dinero de ${selectedUser.username}`)
      .setTimestampp()
      .addFields([
        {
          name: `$${storedBalance.balance}`,
          value: `\u200b`,
        },
      ])
      .setFooter({
        text: client.user.tag,
        iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
      });

      await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embedecon],
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }
  },
};```
````